# CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL on std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, cppunit

I want to test if my application returns a nullptr unique ptr. I have tried a few things but nothing get through the compiler. I hope someone has already tried and found a way to make this work. Some things i have tried:

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> some_class_ptr;

CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>(), some_class_ptr);
```

gives: libcppunit/include/cppunit/TestAssert.h|49|error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘ost << x’|

Inside TestAssert.h:

```
template <class T>
void assertEquals( const T& expected,
                   const T& actual,
                   SourceLine sourceLine,
                   const std::string &message )
{
  if ( !assertion_traits<T>::equal(expected,actual) ) // lazy toString conversion...
  {
    Asserter::failNotEqual( assertion_traits<T>::toString(expected),
                            assertion_traits<T>::toString(actual),
                            sourceLine,
                            message );
  }
}
```

---

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(nullptr, some_class_ptr);
```

gives: /tests/SomeTestClass.cpp|432|error: no matching function for call to ‘assertEquals(std::nullptr_t, std::unique_ptr&, CppUnit::SourceLine, const char [1])’|

---

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(nullptr, some_class_ptr.get());
```

gives: /tests/SomeTestClass.cpp|432|error: no matching function for call to ‘assertEquals(std::nullptr_t, std::unique_ptr::pointer, CppUnit::SourceLine, const char [1])’|

---

I think the first one should be the correct one but it is not compiling. Can anyone give me a correct construction for this ?

Comment: Wont static casting to same type work?

Comment: I don't think so as that would suffer from the same problems as example 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL` requires its arguments to be of exactly the same type.](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/lastest/group___assertions.html#ga3)  Since you don't need to be able to output a representation of the `nullptr` argument, you can just use `CPPUNIT_ASSERT`:

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT(nullptr == some_class_ptr);
```

or

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT(!some_class_ptr);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works wonderfull. To bad i can't use ASSERT_EQUAL, it looks better imho.

Comment: This is so annoying compared to gtest where this sort of stuff just works

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be with `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL`, but I can't see any good reason to use that. I assume there is a `CPPUNIT_ASSERT` or the like (check the documentation or sources). Then just write `CPPUNIT_ASSERT( some_class_ptr().get() == 0 )`, or really any expression you prefer for checking pointer nullness.